# How do i make the font smaller for .js label

Tags: javascript, css

I have a .js file with this custom code below:

```
var aiCustomConfig = {

 toolbarRightButtons: [

   { label: "Verbose logging enabled - performance may be reduced", iconClass: "fa fa-exclamation-triangle fa-lg", clickFunction: function() {} }

 ],
 helpURL: ""
}
```

Essentialy it is creating a toolbar button and has the `label:` but the text is too big. Is there a way i can make the text size of this label smaller?

Comment: For what library? What you describe is controlled with `font-size` CSS property. But from this code it's not clear how to apply this rule.

Comment: I think dijit might be the library?

Answer (score 0):

The part where you define the font size is independent of the provided snippet, as it provides only the content and a definition of the according font-awesome icon next to it. This is using by the way some large preset, e.g. `fa-lg`.

To define the size of the label you have to look into the CSS definitions which are used by your application, or the way your application generates the label and its CSS. There will be either already a place to overwrite the font size or you need to create a CSS definition for this label.